# event.stopPropagation для конкретного обработчика

Tags: html, dom, javascript

**Дано:**

*1)* Дерево элементов (многоуровневое меню)

*2)* 2 функции-обработчика для элементов меню (условно **f1()** и **f2()**)

```
$('#menu li').mouseleave(function(event) {
    f1(this);
    f2(this);
})
```

Каждая из этих функций обрабатывает все элементы li вверх по дереву элементов

**Задача:**

Запретить **только** функции **f2()** "идти" вверх по дереву и обрабатывать родительские элементы

```
$('#menu li').mouseleave(function(event) {
    f1(this);
    event.stopPropagation(); //Запрещает "распространение" обеих функций
    f2(this);
})
```

Comment: если функции "ваши", вызывайте `f2()` в конце `f1()` после `event.stopPropagation()`. Можно даже передавать f2 в f1 как необязательный параметр (удобно при использовании данных функций не только в данном контексте)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Требуемая задача решена путём проверки **event.relatedTarget**.
При *первом* срабатывании события, **event.relatedTarget** является родительским элементом относительно **this**, но не при *последующих*. Вот таким нехитрым способом проверки на *"Отцовство"* удалось решить задачу.
**Но:** Неясность с event.stopPropagation остаётся открытой.

Answer (score 1):

Я не большой спец в идиоматическом JS, так что может быть, это концептуально неверное решение. Но всё же: попробуйте хранить флаг в event'е.

```
$('#menu li').mouseleave(function(event) {
    f1(this);
    if (!event.hasOwnProperty('f2allowed'))
    {
        f2(this);
        event.f2allowed = false;
    }
})
```

Comment: Данный пример работать не будет, но если хранить флаг в переменной, объявленной выше функции, то это будет решением

Comment: @Getans: Почему не будет? В функцию будет приходить каждый раз другой объект `event`? Если хранить флаг в глобальной переменной, не может ли быть проблема с несколькими одновременными mouseleave'ами? Глобальные переменные всегда казались мне подозрительными. И да, как сбросить глобальный флаг после отработки события? (Я не специалист, поэтому мне интересно.)

Answer (score 0):

событие **mouseleave** не всплывает по определению, используйте mouseout

```
$('#menu li').mouseout(function(event) {    
     f1(this);    
     f2(this,event.target||event.srcElement);
});
function f2(a,b){
    if(a==b){
        // делаем то, что надо
    }
}
```

Comment: mouseleave применяется к каждому li, сначала к внутреннему и после поднимается по всем вышестоящим. event.stopPropagation() останавливает "поднятие", но для обеих функций сразу. Использование mouseout в моём случае невозможно.

Comment: тогда, возможно, поможет эта [статья][1]

  [1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-events#события-mouseenter-и-mouseleave